# Problem with reading data from file in Python

Tags: python

EDIT:
Thanks for fixing it! Unfortunatelly, it messed up the logic. I'll explain what this program does. It's a solution to a task about playing cards trick. There are N cards on the table. First and Second are numbers on the front and back of the cards. The trick can only be done, if the visible numbers are in non-decreasing order. Someone from audience can come and swap places of cards. M represents how many cards will be swapped places. A and B represent which cards will be swapped. Magician can flip any number of cards to see the other side. The program must tell, if the magician can do the trick.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Pair = namedtuple("Pair", ["first", "second"])
pairs = []

with open('data.txt', 'r') as data, open('results.txt', 'w') as results:
    n = data.readline()
    n = int(n)
    for _ in range(n):
        first, second = (int(x) for x in data.readline().split(':'))
        first, second = sorted((first, second))
        pairs.append(Pair(first, second))  # add to the list by appending
    m = data.readline()
    m = int(m)
    for _ in range(m):
        a, b = (int(x) for x in data.readline().split('-'))
        a -= 1
        b -= 1
        temp = pairs[a]
        pairs[a] = pairs[b]
        pairs[b] = temp
        p = -1e-9
        ok = True
        for k in range(0, n):
            if pairs[k].first >= p:
                p = pairs[k].first
            elif pairs[k].second >= p:
                p = pairs[k].second
            else:
                ok = False
                break
            if ok:
                results.write("YES\n")
            else:
                results.write("NO\n")
```

data:

```
4
2:5
3:4
6:3
2:7
2
3-4
1-3
```

results:

```
YES
YES
YES
YES
YES
YES
YES
```

What should be in results:

```
NO
YES
```

Comment: Python NameError is because n was declared in the previous for block: lines 9 to 11. n is no longer available to the next block starting from line 12.

Comment: @Promocja, You keep changing the question, and render the answer inappropriate. Maybe you need to work a little more on the code and open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The code is full of bugs: you should write and test it incrementally instead of all at once. It seems that you started using `readlines` (which is a good way of managing this kind of work) but you kept the rest of the code in a reading one by one style. If you used `readlines`, the line `for i, line in enumerate(data):` should be changed to `for i, line in enumerate(lines):`.

Anyway, here is a corrected version with some explanation. I hope I did not mess with the logic.

```py
from collections import namedtuple
Pair = namedtuple("Pair", ["first", "second"])

# The following line created a huge list of "Pairs" types, not instances
# pairs = [Pair] * (2*200*1000+1)
pairs = []

with open('data.txt', 'r') as data, open('results.txt', 'w') as results:
    n = data.readline()
    n = int(n)
    # removing the reading of all data...
    # lines = data.readlines()
    # m = lines[n]
    # removed bad for:     for i, line in enumerate(data):
    for _ in range(n):  # you don't need the index
        first, second = (int(x) for x in data.readline().split(':'))
        # removed unnecessary recasting to int
        # first = int(first)
        # second = int(second)
        # changed the swapping to a more elegant way
        first, second = sorted((first, second))
        pairs.append(Pair(first, second))  # we add to the list by appending
    # removed unnecessary for: once you read all the first and seconds,
    # you reached M
    m = data.readline()
    m = int(m)
    # you don't need the index... indeed you don't need to count (you can read
    # to the end of file, unless it is malformed)
    for _ in range(m):
        a, b = (int(x) for x in data.readline().split('-'))
        # removed unnecessary recasting to int
        # a = int(a)
        # b = int(b)
        a -= 1
        b -= 1
        temp = pairs[a]
        pairs[a] = pairs[b]
        pairs[b] = temp
        p = -1e-9
        ok = True
        for k in range(0, n):
            if pairs[k].first >= p:
                p = pairs[k].first
            elif pairs[k].second >= p:
                p = pairs[k].second
            else:
                ok = False
                break
            if ok:
                results.write("YES\n")
            else:
                results.write("NO\n")
```

**Response previous to edition**

`range(1, 1)` is empty, so this part of the code:

```
for i in range (1, 1):
    n = data.readline()
    n = int(n)
```

does not define `n`, at when execution gets to line 12 you get an error.

You can remove the `for` statement, changing those three lines to:

```
n = data.readline()
n = int(n)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have another problem. Now I realised, the program doesn't even execute my loop (12th line), it just skips to closing filestreams.

Comment: You're a legend! Unfortunatelly, it messed up the logic. I'll explain what this program does.
It's a solution to a task about playing cards trick. There are N cards on the table. First and Second are numbers on the front and back of the cards. The trick can only be done, if the visible numbers are in non-decreasing order. Someone from audience can come and swap places of cards. M represents how many cards will be swapped places. A and B represent which cards will be swapped. Magician can flip any number of cards to see the other side. The program must tell, if the magician can do the trick.